# Laravel - JQuery number input, adding negative value and thousand separator

Tags: jquery, laravel

i have an input number that has an thousand separator like this:

[image]

here is the input:

```
<input type="text" name="nett_budget" id="nett_budget" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value>
```

for this one i was using the `numeric.js` for the thousand separator, here is the script:

```
$(function(){
            $('#nett_budget').number(true);
});
```

and then i had an another script which is used to make the input become negative like this :

[image]

And here is the script for the negative value :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var Budget = document.getElementById('nett_budget');
                Budget.oninput = handleInputPositif;

                function handleInputPositif(e){
                    Budget.value = Math.abs(e.target.value);
                }
                function handleInputNegatif(e){
                    Budget.value = -Math.abs(e.target.value);          
                }

            $(document).on('change',"#categoryid", function(){
                if($(this).val()=='3'){
                    $('#nett_budget').val("");
                    Budget.oninput = handleInputNegatif;
                }else{
                    $('#nett_budget').val("");
                    Budget.oninput = handleInputPositif;
                }
            });
        });
```

As you can see, when user select the `category_id` = 3, the script will input a `-Math.abs` into the input value, but the field is cleared when it reach a million, so far i have modify the `jquery.number.js` and change the thousand separator to `.`, anyone has an better alternative or solution? any help is really appreciated, thank you!.

here is my `category_id` input :

```
<div class="row mg-t-20">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">CATEGORY:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 mg-t-10 mg-sm-t-0">
                                <select class="form-control select2 select2-show-search" name="category_id" id="category_id" data-placeholder="CATEGORY">
                                    <option label="Choose One..."></option>
                                    @foreach(\App\Enums\CategoryType::getValues() as $categorytype)
                                    <option value="{{ $categorytype }}">{{ strtoupper(\App\Enums\CategoryType::getDescription($categorytype)) }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and here is the `enum` :

```
final class CategoryType extends Enum
{
    const NewOrder = 1;
    const AdditionalOrder = 2;
    const CancelOrder = 3;
    const Paid = 4;
    const Bonus = 5;

    public static function parseDatabase($value)
    {
        switch ($value) {
            case self::NewOrder:
                return '1';
                break;

            case self::AdditionalOrder:
                return '2';
                break;

            case self::CancelOrder:
                return '3';
                break;

            case self::Paid:
                return '4';
                break;
            
            case self::Bonus:
                return '5';
                break;     


            default:
                return (int) $value;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *field is cleared when it reach a million*? try this https://jsfiddle.net/ukt5rjnm/

Comment: sorry i try to explain it as much as i can, it's something like when i tried to input like `1.000.000`, if i add another number the field is just cleared and back to 0.

Comment: the `jsfiddle` is working thank you!, but now it seems im missing the  `-Math.abs()`, i'll update my question just to let know that my category_id is still number, but those number is using enum, thank you!.